# Best solution for particle collision simulation

Tags: animation, physics

[image: simulate these leafs dynamics]

Hello everybody,
I am working on recreating the model you can see in the picture. The model is wearing a "helmet" cover in leaves. Although the 3d model will not be moving, I want the leaves to be affected by a soft wind or turbulence, so they will move slightly.
I am using blende 3.4. So far I have tried the old hair system. I render the strands as objects (I use a simple leaf model) but there is no autocollision between the strands. It does not look realistic. I have been taking a look to the new hair system but it looks like autocollision isn´t implemented either.
Which would be the best way to go about this?Maybe using "standard" particle system so the leaves can interact with each other?I would appreciate any help on this. I have been using Max for the last 10 years but I am new to blender. Thank you for your time!

Comment: There's no collision with the particles so I guess you'll need to move them together or move them slightly enough that they don't intersect?

Comment: In this particular case, you could convert the particles into a mesh, create a pin group for the roots and add a Cloth simulation for it which has self-collision. It is also affected by force fields like Wind. You need a high strength value like 40 to 120. Here is a quick test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlA8q.gif

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I am definitely going to give it a try to the cloth solution. It could be potentially faster than having to animate every leaf individually